# Create Custom Performance Counters in Inno Setup Installer

Tags: inno-setup

I need to create some custom performance counters in my installer.  My installer is made with Inno Setup (this can't change at this time).

In c# i can create the counters using PerformanceCounterCategory.Create (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e3s61wf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(
        "Multi Counter Category", "Category help",
        PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, CounterDatas);
```

But i can't find anything about creating them through Inno Setup. Any examples or documentation on how to do this.

thanks
scott

Comment: Are you trying to call C# code from Inno Setup? That is not possible. But you can create .exe file with C# and call it from Inno Setup.

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up doing was adding a command line parameter to my .exe of /RegPerfCounters.  When the exe is launched with this parameter it will register the performance counters and exit.

Then in inno i added the following line in [Run] section

```
Filename: {app}\Monitor.exe; Parameters: /RegPerfCounters; StatusMsg: {cm:RegisteringPerfCounters}; Components: client; Flags: runhidden;
```